# Difference of these two C++ functions

Tags: c++, function

Consider:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class pair
{
    private:
        T1 a;

    public:
        T1 & first(){return a;}
        T1 first() const{return a;}
}
```

What's the difference between these two "first" functions? When are they used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one returns a reference to `a`, the second returns a copy of `a` and is declared `const`. That means, whenever you have an object of class `pair` the first one will be called if the object  is not declared `const`, and the second if it is.

However the standard way IMHO would be to use this to avoid the copying:

```
T1 & first(){return a;}
const T1 & T1 first() const{return a;}
```

PS: There's a semicolon missing in your code.

Comment: I find it somewhat disturbing that not only I am the only one pointing out that returning a reference to a member might not be the wisest thing to do, but the answer actually *encouraging* this behaviour without so much as a caveat gets chosen as "correct".

Comment: Whether it's good practice to return a reference to member (in `first()`) depends on the use case. However I really don't see any problem with returning a const-qualified reference in `second()`. If you see a problem with `second()`, please let me know.

Comment: No specific problem, especially not in the `const` case. But I've seen too many beginners trying to "avoid copying" at all costs while completely ignoring things like encapsulation, locality etc. when performance wasn't even an issue that I am somewhat allergic to "letting it stand" without a firm caveat that this isn't what OO is about. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> What's the difference between these two "first" functions? when are they used?

The first one (`T1 first() const`) will be called when the object is `const` qualified and will return a copy of `a`, the other (`T1 & first()`) when the object not `const` qualified and will return a reference to `a`.

As an example:

```
pair<int, int> x;
const pair<int, int> y;
x.first(); // T1 & first()
y.first(); // T1 first() const
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is returning a *reference*, so you get access to `a` directly. If you act on the return value, you are acting on the `a` from the instance.

Code smell, breaking encapsulation.

The second one returns a *copy* of `a`. Because you cannot change the `a` inside the instance that way, the function can be `const`, i.e. you can call it on constant instances of the class (which you cannot with the first function).

I assume that the `t1` (sp!) in the template declaration is a typo, right? Should be `T1`.

Answer (score 0):

The one with the const is a const function that returns a copy of a.  The second is non-const and returns a reference to a.

If you pass pair to a function by const reference you cannot call the non const version.

Answer (score 0):

```
T1 & first(){return a}
```

Returns a reference to your 'a' object of type T1. Changing a returned object will change object inside the object it was returned from.

```
T1 first() const{return a;}
```

Returns a copy of 'a'. Doing changes to returned object won't change object it was copied from.